# Request Entity Too Large when want to upload file to Strapi

Tags: reactjs, strapi

I am trying to upload PDF file, 20 - 40 pages. I am getting:

```
413 Request Entity Too Large
```

Is there any way to increase max file size for upload?

Comment: You might want to update your config in `strapi` -> https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/1975

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the left menu you can click on `Plugins` then in the cog of the `Upload` plugin.
And you will have an option to increase the limit size value.

But this issue can also come from your nginx configuration that not allows the large file size. So make sure you well-configured nginx for this case.

Comment: I dont have "Upload" on my Plugins... what i am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't have Upload neither in Plugins and I surely cannot click anything there.

Answer (score 7):

You need your **config/middlewares.js** looks like this (using strapi v4)

```
module.exports = [
  'strapi::errors',
  'strapi::security',
  'strapi::cors',
  'strapi::poweredBy',
  'strapi::logger',
  'strapi::query',
  {
    name: "strapi::body",
    config: {
      formLimit: "256mb", // modify form body
      jsonLimit: "256mb", // modify JSON body
      textLimit: "256mb", // modify text body
      formidable: {
        maxFileSize: 200 * 1024 * 1024, // multipart data, modify here limit of uploaded file size
      },
    },
  },
  'strapi::favicon',
  'strapi::public',
];
```

Comment: Having a hard time googling what these values represent `200 * 1024 * 1024`